# "Вы не достойны быть..." или "Вы недостойны быть..."?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

*Фрагмент предложения: **"Вы не/достойны быть моими учениками!"***

Предполагаю, что писать нужно раздельно, но найти подтверждение в правилах не смогла. Пожалуйста, подскажите!

Answer (score 1):

> > Интуитивно чувствую, что писать нужно раздельно, но найти подтверждение в правилах не смогла.

И правильно. Потому что оба варианта допустимы. Я бы выбрал слитное написание.

Comment: Дорогой безымянный модератор, какие объяснения? "Подробные объяснения" от дилетантов, которых тут подавляющее большинство, выглядят смешно и нелепо. Не хочу уподобляться... Или мне привести примеры?.. Поэтому достаточно того, что ответ верен. Престиж ресурса возрастёт от удаления верных ответов? – ради бога. К тому же, автор вопроса вроде бы ничего не заявлял?